# Pains deserializing C# JSON string

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-3, deserialization

I am trying to post some data to my MVC 3 controller through a hidden text field that contains some JSON.  I have that JSON passed in via string coursesList.  Anyone have an idea why this is not working?

All I'm doing is making a byte [] out of the JSON string, writing it to a MemoryStream, and deserializing that stream -- or, attempting to.  BookCourse bc always ends up with null properties.

Here's something like the JSON I would be using:

```
[{"coursesection":"1234","netlogon":"jsmith","label":"CRSE-1313 Generic Course Titling ~ Joe Smith"}]
```

And here's the object to be deserialized into:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace xxxx.Models
{
    [DataContract]
    public class BookCourse
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string coursesection { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string netlogon { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string label { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Finally, the controller action code to do it --

```
var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(coursesList);

// Deserialize byte array to data type
var stream = new MemoryStream();
stream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
var crs = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(BookCourse));
stream.Position = 0;

// Read stream to object
ad.CourseSectionIDs = new List<int>();
try
{
    var bc = (BookCourse) crs.ReadObject(stream);
    while (bc.coursesection != null)
    {
        cs.AssociateCourseBook(bc.netlogon, bc.coursesection, ad.ISBN);
        bc = (BookCourse)crs.ReadObject(stream);
    }
}
catch (System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException e)
{
    // Is this best practice for handling "none"?
}
```

Comment: Post a sample of the json you're sending up.

Comment: Have you stepped through it with the debugger to see what's happening?

Comment: Are you posting the json object via an ajax call? If so, it should work out of the box by simply having a corresponding parameter (with the properties coursesection, netlogon & label) in your action signature.

Comment: @markpsmith -- Yes.  I can pretty well get the string back from the byteArray.  I do assume I'm writing to the MemoryStream correctly.  When I call the deserialize function, the bc object is filled with null property values.

Comment: @nieve -- No, I'm just passing in string data from a hidden input at postback.

Comment: I think you need to remove the wrapping square brackets- these signify an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON string represents a collection of BookCourse, not a single BookCourse. So adapt your code:

```
var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(BookCourse[]));
```

and then:

```
var bookCourses = (BookCourse[])crs.ReadObject(stream);
```

or if you want to work with a single BookCourse you will need to change your JSON string and remove the wrapping square brackets which represent a collection.

Answer (score 1):

Darin is correct, here is the change if you want to do it on a contract level.

```
[DataContract]
public class BookCourse
{
    [DataMember]
    public string coursesection { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string netlogon { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string label { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class BookCourceCollection
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<BookCourse> Collection;

    public static BookCourceCollection ReturnCollection(string jsonString)
    {
        MemoryStream ms;
        BookCourceCollection collection;

        using (ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString)))
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(BookCourceCollection));
            collection = ser.ReadObject(ms) as BookCourceCollection;
        }

        return collection;
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
 string jsonString = "Your JSON string from the front end";

var bookCourceObject = BookCourseCollection.ReturnCollection(jsonString);
foreach (BookCourse bookCourse in bookCourceObject.Collection)
{
    cs.AssociateCourseBook(bookCourse.netlogon, bookCourse.coursesection, bookCourse.ISBN);
}
```